# How to abort controller action in play framework 2.1 when client cancel request or client socket is closed?

Tags: request, playframework-2.0

I am testing play framework 2.1 to check what happen when client cancel request or socket is closed from client side. I created this simple program:

```
package controllers;
```

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

`public static Result index() {

    try{
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println(i+"\n");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("\nexcepción capturada");
    }
    return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
}`

}

If I cancel request from client (google chrome) the loop isn't aborted. I think this could be a problem in real world application, not making a loop, but doing a "heavy" query to database.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid making active waiting/checking using a limit in all my "heavy" operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there was no answer I asked on the google group for play 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/play-framework/POvFA3moXug
and here is what **James Roper** from Typesafe said:

> Play offers **no such feature**.  However, there are other ways to achieve
>   the same thing, for example, if you have a long running request, you
>   could do it as a **websockets** request, which let's you easily detect
>   when the client navigates to a different page.

The latest release as of today is play-2.2.0-RC1 (in case they add support later).